# Column width not coming properly in runnable jar when I use Calibri font in apache poi library

Tags: java, swing, apache-poi

I have built a java application using apache poi.
**It is a simple swing gui app and it generates excel using apache poi library.** After generating sheet I have set autofit column, which is **working perfectly fine when I am running the application with RAD**. Now I have **generated runnable jar**(which is my requirement) and it generates excel **but all columns after second column are hiding behind one another**.

**I removed autosize column and columns didnt hide behind each other. But I want my columns to be autosized according to text. Please tell me what is the correct way to use autosize. And why its working in RAD and not in runnable jar.**

I get this is font issue. I removed the line where I am setting font name and it worked good. Now my question is how can I use Calibri font. Please help.

Here is my code for writing excel:

```
public class Excel {
    HSSFWorkbook wb;
    HSSFFont head, defFont;

    public Excel() {
        wb = new HSSFWorkbook);
        //create header font to use Calibri and bold text
        //create default font to use Calibri and normal text
    }

    public void sheetGen() {
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.creatSheet("sheet1");

        //create style
        //create each row and column
        for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
            if (i != 2)
                sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);  //this is not working in runnable jar
        }
        //write workbook
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) with the relevant code that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @CanadianDavid: I have provide my code which I am using to create excel. I cannot attach screenshot of excel generated. Apologies for that.

Comment: Are all the relevant fonts installed + available to Java to use on your other environment? (My hunch is that they're not)

Comment: @Gagravarr: I am not able to see Calibri font in font_metrics.properties file created inside the jar. But is there any way I can include. I mean to say how can I install calibri in java.

Comment: How to install a font for use on Java depends on what OS you're running on, and likely also needs to be a brand new question

Comment: @aterai: Thanks for editing the question. I will keep these things in mind while posting other questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On some platforms, `Calibri` is a third party font; for example, it is included with Microsoft Office on Mac OS X. Instead, use the desired *logical* fonts from among the five [font families](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html) defined by the Java platform. For example,

Header:  `new Font(Font.SansSerif, Font.BOLD | Font.ITALIC, 14)`

Default:  `new Font(Font.Serif, Font.PLAIN, 12)`